# update fct in python constructors

Tags: python

I have come across in ["Artificial Intelligence: A modern approach"](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/search.py) code repository the following piece of code that I have never seen before:

```
  def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
    update(self, state=state, parent=parent, action=action,
           path_cost=path_cost, depth=0)
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1
```

They seem to be using an `update` function to redefine the parameters of the constructor, to allow for alternative arguments. I looked everywhere in the code and could not find a self-defined function named `update`. Is this allowed in python? I couldn't find it online.

Comment: see, it's real AI: you need a supercomputer just to understand the code! :) Just kidding. Excellent Q and A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not one of Python's [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), so as it's not defined locally or listed in:

```
import math, random, sys, time, bisect, string
```

*(ulgh!)* it must have come from the only other `import` in the file:

```
from utils import *
```

(this is why [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says *"Wildcard imports should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace"*...).

---

Checking in [that file](http://aima-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/utils.py) we find:

```
def update(x, **entries):
    """Update a dict; or an object with slots; according to entries.
    >>> update({'a': 1}, a=10, b=20)
    {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
    >>> update(Struct(a=1), a=10, b=20)
    Struct(a=10, b=20)
    """
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        x.update(entries)
    else:
        x.__dict__.update(entries)
    return x
```

---

The use of this function slightly simplifies what would otherwise look like:

```
def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
    "Create a search tree Node, derived from a parent by an action."
    self.state = state
    self.parent = parent
    self.action = action
    self.path_cost = path_cost
    self.depth = 0
    if parent:
        self.depth = parent.depth + 1
```